# How many plus signs needed to to get a given sum?

Tags: dynamic-programming

I was doing a problem on topcoder and I came across a DP problem (http://goo.gl/hjeaS)

This should have an efficient dp solution, but I'm stuck. I took an array res[i][j][k] to store the sub problems, but I can't figure out the execution, especially the finer details.

r[i][j][k] would store the minimum no. of plus signs to be inserted between i and j, to get a sum k.
So, I looped over i,j & k, inserting a plus sign at every location between i & j. The minimum would be obtained after looping through all elements i to j(for a particular sum, k).
I'm not sure about the initial values of the array, though and what the limits should be. Is there a more efficient solution ? (mine seems to be O(n³k))

P.S I know there's another similar question, but none of the answers really explain the logic/code behind the dp solution to the problem.

Comment: You probably need to show a little more of what you have tried.  Do you have any code?  Right now, your question comes across as "show me the answer".  Also your first link goes to a site requiring a username/password.  That's of no use.

Comment: How are you breaking up the sub-problems? Have you considered what your base case is for dropping out of the DP? Consider how you would build or extend the successive cases using an iterative approach. You'll also need to consider backtracking.

Comment: Sorry for the link! Fixed that and I've added my approach.

Answer (score 0):

i think 2d array is enough for this problem because all u need to insert is a plus sign, there are no parenthesis or priority, so just use res[i][j] to record data.

let res[i][j] means the minimum no. of plus signs to be inserted for the first i characters, to get a sum j. therefore, the whole time complexity will be O(n^2*k)